# Can I write the Cantor Set as the $\limsup{A_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf, cantor-set

From Richard Bass' Real Analysis Text I have the following problem.

Let $m$ be a Lebesgue measure. Suppose for each $n$, $A_n$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0, 1]$. Let $B$ consist of those points $x$ that is in infinitely many of the $A_n$.

Give an example where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{m(A_n)} = \infty$, but $m(B) = 0$.

I know that $$B = \limsup{A_n} = \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty{A_n}$$

My question is, can I write the Cantor set, in the same form that $B$ is described in.

If not, I would appreciate hints towards the problem itself.

Comment: I'm aware of one explicit way to describe the Cantor set, but it is not exactly what you need. Anyway, I like how it looks, so here it is! $${\displaystyle {\mathcal {C}}=\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty }\bigcup _{k=0}^{3^{n-1}-1}\left(\left[{\frac {3k+0}{3^{n}}},{\frac {3k+1}{3^{n}}}\right]\cup \left[{\frac {3k+2}{3^{n}}},{\frac {3k+3}{3^{n}}}\right]\right).}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some pretty simple examples - much simpler than the Cantor set - with $m(A_n) = 1/n$ and $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 ... $, in which case the formula for $B$ becomes much simpler too.

Comment: If the $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint then necessarily $\sum m(A_n) \le 1$ so the hypothesis cannot hold.  (But if the $A_n$ were pairwise disjoint then $B = \emptyset$ so the conclusion would be trivial.)

Comment: You're right. Twice. The example I thought up seemed so simple that I thought it must be violating some unstated assumption, and "pairwise disjointness" was the first possibility I considered. I'll edit that out of my response to make it clearer.